# errror in code : module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'ConvTranspose2D'

Tags: deep-learning

def make_gen_block(self,input_channels,output_channels,kernel_size=3,stride=2,final_layer = False):
10          if not final_layer :
---> 11             return nn.Sequential(nn.ConvTranspose2D(input_layer,output_layer,kernel_size,stride),
12                    nn.BatchNorm2d(output_channels),
13                     nn.ReLU(inplace = True),)

AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'ConvTranspose2D'
what is the solution?

transpose in pytorch

Answer (score 0):

It should be `nn.ConvTranspose2d`

I had the same problem. More on [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html)